# Codeigniter twitter bootstrap login using Jquery

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

Am fairly new to using Jquery and am  creating a login for a simple site am creating using CodeIgniter and bootstrap. After submitting the Log in button, it won't show any error or success message, meaning that I don't even know if it actually post the data to the controller
here's my code,

Jquery Code

```
     <script>
  //Wait until the DOM is fully loaded
  $(document).ready(function(){
     //Listen for the form submit
     $('#loginform').submit(logIn);
   });

//The function that handles the process
function logIn(event)
{
   //Stop the form from submitting
   event.preventDefault();
        //Hide our form
               // $('#loginform').slideUp();

   //Collect our form data.
   var form_data = {
    email : $("[name='email']").val(),
    password : $("[name='password']").val(),

   };

  //Begin the ajax call
  $.ajax({
        url: "admin",
        type: "POST",     
        data: form_data,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,

        success: function (json) {             
            if (json.error==1)
            {
                //Show the user the errors.
               $('#message').html(json.message);
            } else {
                //Hide our form
                $('#loginform').slideUp();
                //Show the success message
                $('#message').html(json.message).show();
            }             
        }
      });
   }
</script>
```

login.php

```
           <?php 
            echo $this->session->flashdata('alert');
        ?>
        <div id="message"></div>
<?php
    $attr = array('class' => 'admin-login form-horizontal well form-signin', 'id' => 'loginform');
    echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>');
?>
<?php echo form_open(site_url('admin'), $attr) ?>
<!--<form action="<?php echo site_url('track-order'); ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-search" id="trackModalform">-->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Track Your Order</label>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" >Email:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-qrcode"></i></span>
               <input type="text" name="email" class="input-block-level email" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">    
        <label class="control-label" >Password:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-key"></i></span>
               <input type="password" name="password" class="input-block-level password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions" style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
        <input type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary " name="signin" value="Sign In!" id="login">
    </div>
</form>
```

my controller

```
    public function index()

{
        if (!file_exists('application/views/admin/index.php'))
        {
            //sorry that page is not available
            show_404();
        }                

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Name', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[50]|valid_email');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[5]');


        if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
        {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => '1', 'message' => validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-error"><strong>Error!</strong> ', '</div>')));
        } else {
            //Save the data to the database, of course you will need all the data first.
           if($this->admin_model->validate_admin_login()):
             //Send the success to our javascript file.
             echo json_encode(array('error' => '0', 'message' => '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> You have been registered!</div>'));

           endif;     
        }

        $data['title'] =    ucfirst('Admin - Home');
        $data['currentpage'] =    'home';

        $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
}
```

model

```
public function validate_admin_login()
{
    $this->str = do_hash($this->input->post('password')); // SHA1 
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->str);
    $query = $this->db->get('ip_admin');

    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
         $data['admin_sess'] = $this->admin_model->admin_details($this->input->post('email'));
            $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'is_admin_logged_in' => true
             );     
             $this->session->set_userdata($data);      
        return true;
    }
}

public function admin_details($user)
{         
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('ip_admin')->where('email', $user);
    $query = $query->get();
    return $data['admin_sess'] = $query->row();       
}
```

I don't really responding or outputting any message to indicate success or failure, maybe I got everything wrong to start with.

I need it to query the db, returns the message for me on the view page using the json parameter on my controller.

Thanks all.

Comment: That's because you're mixing response type, your login function does output html & on top of it output a json string using echo. You'll have to handle both ajax & non-ajax request using a simple check like if ( $this->input->is_ajax_request() ) echo json_encode(array()) else $this->load->view('xxx');

Comment: Ahmad is correct. At second glance, there's no halting point in the function returning a specific result, it's returning the json as well as the html.

Comment: Please Ahmad and Stephen Hero, can you guys provide me a some lines of code?
I can take it up from there.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you guys, could maybe rearrange the controller method for me, am really stuck, completely new to jquery.

Comment: Edited my original answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add a data in var_data like this:

```
    var form_data = {
         email : $("[name='email']").val(),
         password : $("[name='password']").val(),
         //add a data which is
         ajax: '1'
       };
```

And in your controller check if it is POST'ed:

```
    if($this->input->post('ajax'){
       //do something
     }else{
       //do something
    }
```

so from there you could check if it is working or not. and also install firebug for debugging purposes in Firefox. In Chrome try to inspect element and see console

Comment: worked a bit, making some progress.
I'll post my code after I got them all working

Answer (score 0):

I honestly haven't gone through all your code as it really isn't that complicated, instead I'd like to suggest you install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to debug your jquery if you haven't already installed it. Its essential when developing with javascript. It will print any errors or success as events are called and handled.

How to use: [Firebug FAQ](http://getfirebug.com/faq/)

## EDIT:

As you asked for code:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
{
    echo json_encode(array('error' => '1', 'message' => validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-error"><strong>Error!</strong> ', '</div>')));
} else {
    //Save the data to the database, of course you will need all the data first.
   if($this->admin_model->validate_admin_login()):
     //Send the success to our javascript file.
     echo json_encode(array('error' => '0', 'message' => '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> You have been registered!</div>'));

   endif;     
}

$data['title'] =    ucfirst('Admin - Home');
$data['currentpage'] =    'home';

$this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
```

Wtihin this block, you're echo'ing json once and then spitting out the HTML view afterwards. Just try removing the:

```
$data['title'] =    ucfirst('Admin - Home');
$data['currentpage'] =    'home';

$this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
```

Or create separate controller functions for your requests, things get really messy when you try to stuff everything into a single function.

Comment: I actually have installed Firebug, but I don't seem to get the hang of it

Comment: Do you see any output in the console tab?

Comment: yes, clicking on the All tab, it gave me this

POST http://localhost/paid_projects/iphoneappsonline/admin
 
200 OK
  524ms

I expanded it and on the RESPONSE tab, I see the whole source code from my page written there, all, no other response as it is.

Comment: `{"error":"1","message":"error"}` got this at the top of Firebug Console HTML tab.